# Inequality between successive rows pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to insert a matrix by comparing successive identical rows

1. If successive rows are identical I want to insert 1 otherwise 0 in the matrix.
2. If successive rows are not identical I want to change the column and repeat condition 1

But in my code, if only one column of successive rows is identical it gives 1 (instead of 0,) How can I compare all the values of two rows?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'col1'    :['French', 'French', 'Japanese', 'Chinese', 'Chinese', 'English', 'French', 'Hindi', 'Bengali'],
      'col2'   :['France', 'France', 'Japan',    'China',   'China',   'Canada',  'Canada', 'India',  'India'],
       'col3'  : [0.30,0.30, 0.25, 0.21, 0.21, 0.37, 0.15, 0.40, 0.27] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
group = df.ne(df.shift()).all(1).cumsum().sub(1)
Jac = np.zeros((len(df), group.max()+3), dtype=int) #I need two extra columns
Jac[np.arange(len(df)), group] = 1
 
my output
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0]]

Expected output
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]]

​
​
```

Comment: you want to compare rows or columns. question seems to be bit unclear. can you take few inputs and explain how you formed the output matrix ? i.e (why it is 1 and why it is 0 - for few inputs )

Comment: I want to compare rows.  Only If successive rows are identical I want to insert 1. if they are not identical I want to change the column(in the matrix) and  again repeat above condition (In mu data for the rows canada, and india they are not identical ....

Comment: is it element by element comparison ? can you show some example ?

Comment: yes element by element, all elements of First and second rows are identical so there is 1,1 (on same column) in matrix but for last four rows all elements are not identical  so I want 1,1,1,1 in four different column as in my expected output

Comment: if you are comparing row by row.. `French France 0.30` equals `French France 0.30 `. hence you had 1 in (0,0). 

but `French France 0.30` is not equal to `Japanese Japan 0.25`. then you should have 0 in (1, 0) right ?

And your output will be (8, 1) matrix. how is it 9, 9 matrix ?

Comment: number of data= number of rows  and number of groups =number of columns (and I have two extra columns)                 French France 0.30                                           
                                                        French France 0.30 . are identical so they are same group